# append default headers to each get/post/put/delete request via hacking the net/BaseRequestOptions

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

We are writing an App based on ionic. We need to attach headers `api_token` and `api_key` on every request.

currently we do something ugly like

`getUserProfile(apiToken, apiKey)`

```
//fetch user profile
getUserProfile(api_key: string, api_token: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("API_KEY", api_key);
        headers.append("API_TOKEN", api_token);
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers})

    return this.http.get(UrlService.getUrlUserProfile(), options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
}
```

overall we will have about 450 requests and i refuse to attach each time headers. i'm a ruby developer and in ruby i would simply override the method, throw in headers if we have values and call `super`.
i see that similar technique exist in JavaScript but i'm not sure

- how to define the method
- does it have access to the global saved values?
- where to put the method?

unfortunately i'm not able to find any docs or SO-questions about that topic.

i found a `base_request_options.d.ts` inside the `ionic/net` folder but it seems that i can't simply inject my headers there. would that even be the right spot?

// edit

i put 100 reputation award on this question because it will help us a lot.
summary:

we need to append api_key and api_token to each PUT/POST/DELETE/GET request. we want to append this only at 1 place in the code and not for each request we are building.

Comment: Use angular interceptor concept for solve it. for more detail visit the URL :- https://medium.com/tableless/angular-4-and-ionic-3-add-custom-headers-to-http-requests-11aaf93798d9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";


@Injectable()
export class InterceptedHttp extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        return super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        return super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        return super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        return super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    private updateUrl(req: string) {
        return  req;
    }

    private getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }

        const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('details', 'abc');
        options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        //options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what i would expect as a ruby deloper :-) where do we place that file ?

Comment: Create a file with any name here i am create a file with http.interceptor.ts and put the above code in it,by default it add the header in each request ,according to your methods (get,post,delete..).

Comment: `Cannot find module '../../environments/environment'.`we use ionic 3.6 and that uses angular 4.1

Comment: I am editing the above code here i am removing the environment .

Comment: so where to place the file? i don't get it. `src/app/http_override.ts` ?

Comment: Any where in app folder.

Comment: and in the `app.modules` i need to declare `InterceptedHttp`?

Comment: No need to declare it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a common function that calls `http.get` and call that common function from every function 
where you call `http.get`. This can be also done for all `PUT/POST/DELETE/GET`

user-profile.service.ts

```
import { UtilService } from '/path-to/util.service';

...
constructor(
    private util: UtilService,
    ...
)
...

//fetch user profile
getUserProfile(): Observable<any> {
    // Call the common get function we define in below file
    return this.util.get(UrlService.getUrlUserProfile());
}
```

utils.service.ts

```
export class UtilService {
    ...

    get(url: string): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        // Here I am assuming that you store it in localStorage for global access 
        headers.append("API_KEY", localStorage.getItem("api_key"));
        headers.append("API_TOKEN", localStorage.getItem("api_token"));
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers})
        return this.http.get(url, options)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
    }

    post(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("API_KEY", localStorage.getItem("api_key"));
        headers.append("API_TOKEN", localStorage.getItem("api_token"));
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers})
        return this.http.post(url, data, options)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
    }
    ...

    // Do the same for put, delete etc..
}
```

Now you can just call `getUserProfile` without passing any parameters:

some.component.ts

```
getUserProfile().subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
    // Do whatever you want
}, (err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
    // Some error toast etc..
})
```

Comment: that's a nice idea. we'll try that out

Comment: one question, since we strugle with `storage`, is it save to use simply `localStorage`? is then supported on all devices? currently we tried `this.storage.set("api_key", res.json().API_KEY);`but this literally writes nothing  - means we can't even read it.

Comment: Yes it is widely supported. You can view the list of supported browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage)

Comment: we want to use it for android and ios apps, not for any browser. can we still use it?

Comment: Yes, you can. Technically ionic apps use web view ( browser )